# Remote and local databases in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework

I am working on a WPF application that requires access to a remote database. The problem is:

1. The app does **not** have consistent access to the internet
2. There are multiple instances of the application running

My thought was to get a local copy of the database, log all the interactions with the local database (or someway to queue the interactions for later use), then have the option to sync the remote and local database (send the local commands to the remote database, drop the local database, get the remote database).

[This article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) was pretty helpful, but I have some concerns. The main purpose of the queue is to store updates and inserts to the local table, but this route does not look like it stores the parameters for use (has them commented).

Any suggestions or thoughts on the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably look at message queues (the Microsoft version is called MSMQ and is built into Windows. Other message queues are available). They are designed for exactly this sort of scenario.

Essentially, your application write an event to it's local message queue. This will  attempt to send it to the remote queue (on the database in this case) periodically, providing for reliable message delivery.

On the database queue you typically have a listener watching the queue and writing any events it receives to the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!